# How can I tell if a ctypes integer type is big endian?

Tags: python, ctypes

Consider the following:

```
le = ctypes.c_uint32.__ctype_le__
be = ctypes.c_uint16.__ctype_be__
```

How can I write a function `is_bigendian(cls)` that behaves as you would expect:

```
>>> is_bigendian(le)
False
>>> is_bigendian(be)
True
```

Does `ctypes` expose this information somewhere?

Comment: [`CreateSwappedType()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L1833) shows no way to distinguish between them, so you may be SOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only possible way is:

```
if ctypes.c_uint8.__ctype_be__.__name__.endswith('_be'):
    def is_bigendian(cls):
        return cls.__name__.endswith('_be')
elif ctypes.c_uint8.__ctype_le__.__name__.endswith('_le'):
    def is_bigendian(cls):
        return not cls.__name__.endswith('_le')
else:
    raise RuntimeError
```

Which is hard to spot, because `repr(ctypes.c_uint8.__ctype_be__)` doesn't show the class name correctly.

Comment: I might suggest using a `c_uint16` instead of a `c_uint8`. Nowadays it looks both `c_uint8` are the same type. (And rightfully so.)